# Can I determine how much data is queued up on an incoming TCP client stream (in C#)?

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a small TCP client that connects to a server.  Periodically during the connection
I'd like to be able to query the stream to see how much data has queued up (the sender may be faster than the receiver, so i'd like to be able to throw away packets occasionally)
Is there any way to determine how much data is queued up on a TCP client stream in C#?

Comment: Thanks for the answers!!  Didn't notice that property!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [TcpClient.Available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available.aspx) property for that.

**From MSDN:**

> Type: System.Int32
>
> The number of bytes of data received from the
>   network and available to be read.

Answer (score 1):

There's `Socket.Available` and `TcpClient.Available` to tell you how many bytes the socket has queued up.  Note, though, it doesn't tell you how many "packets" were queued up, as TCP makes a point to hide the notion of "packets".  To the OS and your app, a TCP socket just represents a stream of bytes.